# How do we maximize noise immunity between two combinational devices by choosing a single set of voltage thresholds?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I am taking a [course on MIT OCW](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-004-computation-structures-spring-2017/) entitled "Computation Structures". There is a problem in a [problem set](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-004-computation-structures-spring-2017/210fd9514f01b2791eba384f2e2ca366_digital_worksheet.pdf) (Problem 2) that I'd like to solve mathematically. There is a [solution to the problem](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-004-computation-structures-spring-2017/9476106a935f9b65e095c3972990f946_digital_answers.pdf), but it seems to have just the answer but not the work to get there.

Now, there is a lot of domain specific knowledge here to understand what the math problem is.

I will write out the problem statement, then try to explain the domain knowledge, and then reach the math problem.

Here is the problem

> The following are voltage transfer characteristics of single-input,
> single-output devices to be used in a new logic family
>
> [image]
>
> Your job is to choose a single set of signaling thresholds $V_{OL},
>  V_{IL}, V_{OH}$, and $V_{IH}$ to be used with both devices to give the
> best noise margins you can.

Let me try to explain a bit about what the terms in the problem statement mean.

Each of the two devices takes as an input a voltage and generates as output another voltage. Internally, each device interpret an input voltage as a 0 or 1 based on rules that we can summarize in the depiction below

[image]

What this picture says is that input voltages below $V_{IL}$ are considered a 0, and input voltages above $V_{IH}$ are considered a 1. "IL" stands for "Input Low" and "IH" for "Input High".

In addition, when generating an output voltage, the devices are specified to generate some voltage below $V_{OL}$ when they want to signal a 0, and to generate some voltage above $V_{OH}$ when they want to signal a 1. "OL" and "OH" stand for "Output Low" and "Output High".

The graphs in the first picture show what each device outputs given each input.

So, for example, in the first picture, we see that for low input voltages that device generates high output voltages. For the second device, low input voltages generate low output voltages, and high input voltages generate high output voltages.

$V_{IL}, V_{IH}, V_{OL}$, and $V_{OH}$ are like thresholds for specifying rules determining how a device interprets an input voltage and how it generates an output voltage.

Here is an example of choices for these variables for one of the devices

[image]

In this example, we have

$$V_{OL}=0.5$$
$$V_{IL}=1.5$$
$$V_{IH}=3$$
$$V_{OH}=4.4$$

So, any input voltage of below 1.5V is interpreted by this device as a 0. If the device is to output a 1 signal for this input signal, then since it is generating an output voltage of 5 for these input voltages, we need to make sure that  $V_{OH}$ is smaller than or equal to 5.

Similarly, we see from $V_{IH}=3$ that any input voltage above 3 is interpreted as a 1, and to signal a 0 as output we need $V_{OH}$ to be larger than or equal to 0.5 (which are the voltages generated by the device for inputs $\geq 3$).

Note that it must always be the case that

$$V_{OL}<V_{IL}<V_{IH}<V_{OH}\tag{1}$$

otherwise it will be possible to have a valid input signal but an invalid output signal.

That is, for example if $V_{OH}<V_{IH}$ for a device, then if this device wants to output a signal of 1, it may output a voltage $w$ such that $V_{OH}<w<V_{IH}$. But then $w$ would not be interpreted as a 1 by another device with these same thresholds.

Let's see a specification of the parameters that doesn't work.

[image]

where all I did relative to the previous drawing was reduce $V_{IH}$. Notice that the problem here is that there for input voltages between $V_{IH}$ and 3, we have a valid signal input of 1 but the device does not generate an output signal of 0 since these input voltages generate an output voltage that is above $V_{OL}$.

To try to fix this we would need to increase $V_{OL}$, for example as below

[image]

But now this is also an invalid specification because $V_{OL}=2>V_{IL}=1.5$, which violates (1).

We are almost at the actual problem. But first we need to define noise margin, which can be seen in the second picture above (starting at the top of the post). There are two noise margins

$$V_{IL}-V_{OL}\tag{2}$$

$$V_{OH}-V_{IH}\tag{3}$$

These margins represent the amount of error we could have in an output voltage and still have that output signal the intended value. Ie, if the output voltage from a device is $V_{OH}-\epsilon$, then if this value is above $V_{IH}$ it is still a 1 signal.

Finally, noise immunity is defined as the smallest noise margin between the two.

**The math problem**

It is already a math problem to choose the parameters such that noise immunity is maximum, given (1).

Then, the actual math problem in the original problem is to choose a single set of four parameters used for both devices and that maximizes the noise margins when we consider the two devices.

Now, I think this means that we are trying to maximize the sum of the two noise immunities.

For the problem of a single device, what I did was consider multiple cases for the value of $V_{IL}$ and try to go from there.

I might write out this attempt in an answer, so that this question doesn't become too huge.

Anyways, to sum up my question: how does one solve the original problem using just math (ie, without resorting to insights based on the the graphs presented initially)?

Comment: You said "noise immunity is defined as the smallest noise margin between the two". To me this sounds like you want to maximize $\min(|V_{IL}-V_{OL}|, |V_{OH}-V_{IH}|)$, and not the sum of (2) and (3).

Comment: @Sudix You are exactly right. I forgot to remove that part as I already knew it was incorrect. So the question is how to maximize the min of those two noise margins.

Comment: The "correct" framework to obtain a general method to solve this problem in would be that of linear optimization. The drawback here is that learning how to solve an optimization problem once it is formulated as linear programming problem takes some time and effort (in university, you may get a whole course about it). For very special cases like the two examples you've showed, easier methods are possible, which however don't generalize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum of $\min(V_{IL}-V_{OL},V_{OH}-V_{IH})$ is $1$.

*Proof* :

Let us consider the device $B$.

- $V_{IH}\lt 2$ is impossible.
- If $2\le V_{IH}\le 3.5$, then $V_{OH}\le 3V_{IH}-6$, so we have $$V_{OH}-V_{IH}\le 2V_{IH}-6\le 2\times 3.5-6=1$$
- If $3.5\lt V_{IH}$, then $V_{OH}\le 4.5$, so $V_{OH}-V_{IH}\lt 1$.

So, $V_{OH}-V_{IH}\le 1$ always holds.

It follows that $\min(V_{IL}-V_{OL},V_{OH}-V_{IH})\le 1$.

The equality is attained when $V_{OL}=0.5,V_{IL}=1.5,V_{IH}=3.5$ and $V_{OH}=4.5$.

Therefore, the maximum of $\min(V_{IL}-V_{OL},V_{OH}-V_{IH})$ is $1$.$\ \ \blacksquare$